# Cannot access Wordpress site from both locally and externally at the same time

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu-server

I found some answers on here and I've tried a couple of fixes. I can fix this from development stage to production stage by editing the wp-options in phpmyadmin. I just swap the IP addresses from local to public.

Now is there a way to view both without having to go into phpmyadmin?

This is my scenario: I have a local Ubuntu server on a 192.168.1.201 static address and my public IP is 66.103.41.183 I wanted to know why my mobile phone wasn't loading the website so I launched a AWS instance and viewed my public IP. The website was stripped of all CSS. So I googled it and found this solution to change the values in phpmyadmin to 66.103.41.184. Now when I go to my local LAN side of 192.168.1.201 the CSS is stripped again!

I installed Relative URL but it had no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: magenta - I think it may come down to a port forwarding issue but I can't wrap my head around it. Can I port forward my local computer on my LAN to my external IP? Say for example my local computers IP was 192.168.1.25 do I port forward that to port 80 on my router and keep 'siteurl' to my public IP?

Comment: When I try to access the Wordpress site locally it tries to go to the external IP and it times out. When I change the 'siteurl' to my local IP of 192.168.1.201 it works. There's no problem accessing the internet. Just wondering how to simplify accessing it both locally and publicly. I am wondering if there is a way to enter in both those absolute values and how?